# При поиске массива в массиве найденные массивы содержат друг друга

Tags: matlab

Есть код который ищет массив в массиве:

В нем у нас есть 4 Find-а,которые ищутся в М, но вот проблема,каждый Find ищется отдельно,потому в результате они "налазят" друг на друга. Как записать условия,чтобы находились только те Find-ы,которые не содержат друг друга?
Я думаю нужно использовать индексы начала пачки-,но никак не могу придумать как правильно это сделать...

```
n=10; m=1; % размерность исходной матрицы
M=randint(n,m); % тут мы задаем наш "сигнал"

Find1=[0; 1; 1; 1]; % наши критерии "3 из 4"
Find2=[1; 0; 1; 1];
Find3=[1; 1; 0; 1];
Find4=[1; 1; 1; 0];

[h w]=size(Find1);
for i=1length(M)-(h-1));
if isequal(M(ii+(h-1))), Find1); 
disp('Найдено начало пачки')
[M(ii+(h-1))), Find1]
disp('Индекс начала пачки')
N1=i
disp('Индекс конца пачки')
N2=i+(h-1)
end;
end;

[h w]=size(Find2);
for i=1length(M)-(h-1));
if isequal(M(ii+(h-1))), Find2); 
disp('Найдено начало пачки')
[M(ii+(h-1))), Find2]
disp('Индекс начала пачки')
N11=i
disp('Индекс конца пачки')
N21=i+(h-1)
end;
end;

[h w]=size(Find3);
for i=1length(M)-(h-1));
if isequal(M(ii+(h-1))), Find3); 
disp('Найдено начало пачки')
[M(ii+(h-1))), Find3]
disp('Индекс начала пачки')
N12=i
disp('Индекс конца пачки')
N22=i+(h-1)
end;
end;

[h w]=size(Find4);
for i=1length(M)-(h-1));
if isequal(M(ii+(h-1))), Find4); 
disp('Найдено начало пачки')
[M(ii+(h-1))), Find4]
disp('Индекс начала пачки')
N13=i
disp('Индекс конца пачки')
N23=i+(h-1)
end;
end;
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, здесь слишком много повторения кода. Все массивы на поиск можно записать в один cell array "Finds" (они могут быть разного размера), и обращаться по индексам.

Чтобы избежать налегания результатов, в случае обнаружения массива нужно передвинуть индекс i вперёд, после конца найденного массива. Для этого, заменить цикл for на цикл while.

Вот так, примерно:

```
M = floor(rand(30,1)*2);

Finds = {[0; 1; 1; 1], [1; 0; 1; 1], [1; 1; 0; 1], [1; 1; 1; 0]};

i = 1;
while (i<numel(M)) 
    for j=1:numel(Finds)
        [h w]=size(Finds{j});
        if (i+h-1<=numel(M)) && isequal(M(i:i+h-1), Finds{j})
            disp('Найдено начало пачки');
            [M(i:i+h-1), Finds{j}]
            disp('Индекс начала пачки')
            N1 = i
            disp('Индекс конца пачки')
            N2 = i+(h-1)
            i = i+h-1;
            break;
        end
    end
    i=i+1;
end
```